# TFS 2018 Change Agent queue in release to same build agent

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, tfs-2018

I added a new agent Queues to speed up my build process

[image]

When I do the building process, I choose the agent that I will work with,

[image]

but during the Release stage, it does not change, it remains the default agent Queues

[image]

What is the correct way to pass the agent from the build process to the Release process?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Classic release pipelines do not support dynamic pool agents. I think you may use one of the following approaches:

1. Assign Builds to the Default pool and assign Releases to the MAX pool. However, amount of builds is always more than amount of releases.
2. Use only one Default pool and register the second build agent here. In this case, each build or release will wait for a free build agent. You speed up at least 2 times all your build and release runs here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
But I have another question
I have two agents running on two separate machines. What is the best way to have the two agents work together?

Comment: In this case that I mentioned, is the order of folders and files for each agent?
Or it is a shared folder for the same two agents

Comment: @MaxSh pls extend your description and add a use case to your question. Why do you need to run them in such sequence? Each build agent is an independent folder and process that can be on the same machine or different. There is no dependency here. The release just downloads the results of the build.